# Asp.net MVC usage in Eclipse

Tags: asp.net-mvc, eclipse, visual-studio-2012

Can i use Eclipse for ASP.NET MVC ?
Or only visual studio is available , if it can be used in eclipse rather than size compared to visual studio what are best fearures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such plug in, but Visual Studio is pretty great and the Community Version provides everything you need as a beginner. You can, however, utilize MVC using Java in eclipse.

Comment: No problem, if you found this helpful could you click the green "check"